# Optional TPM Key Attestation in AD Certificate Services

Tags: pki, tpm

We have a range of Windows 10 computers in our estate - some with no TPM chip, some with TPM 1.2, and some with TPM 2.0.

I want to configure a certificate template to *optionally* perform TPM Key Attestation if the client is capable, to enable clients that support TPM Key Attestation to do so whilst we phase out non-capable devices.

AD CS exposes the certificate template option "Required, if client is capable", which is [documented](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/component-updates/tpm-key-attestationS) as:

> Allows users on a device that does not support TPM key attestation to
>   continue enrolling for that certificate. Users who can perform
>   attestation will be distinguished with a special issuance policy OID.
>   Some devices might not be able to perform attestation because of an
>   old TPM that does not support key attestation, or **the device not**
>   **having a TPM at all**.

The certificate template is configured as follows:

- Compatibility Settings

  - Certification Authority: Windows Server 2016
  - Certificate recipient: Windows 8.1/Windows Server 2012 R2
- Request Handling

  - Purpose: Signature and encryption
  - Allow private key to be exported: No
  - Archive subject's encryption private key: No
- Cryptography

  - Provider category: Key Storage Provider
  - Algorithm name: RSA
  - Minimum key size: 2048
  - Providers:

    - Microsoft Platform Crypto Provider
    - Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider
  - Request hash: SHA1
- Key Attestation

  - Required, if client is capable
  - Perform attestation based on:

    - User credentials
  - Perform attestation only (do not include issuance policies)

When enrolling for this certificate template on a computer without a TPM chip, the request fails with error:

> An error occurred while enrolling for a certificate. A certificate request could not be created.
>
> Url: ad1.corp.contoso.com\Contoso Root CA
>
> Error: One or more arguments are not correct. 0x800700a0 (WIN32/HTTP: 160 ERROR_BAD_ARGUMENTS)

If Key Attestation is turned off (Required, if client is capable > *None*), the enrollment succeeds. The PKI is otherwise healthy (CDP/AIA accessible, CRLs valid etc), and there is no block on Issuance Policy issuance (e.g. 'Endorsement Key Certificate Verified' can be manually issued into a certificate).

Debug data for the CA is available here: https://pastebin.com/Tu5QiJeY.

Debug data for the client is available here: https://pastebin.com/YTErH9bh